# CXL.Cache support in Linux Kernel

Tags: caching, linux-kernel, pci-e

I am going through the CXL support in Linux Kernel and I found that there is no function or support for cxl.cache. I'm confused if the cache part is not yet implemented in linux kernel or if the kernel should not have access to the cache commands?

(I have seen up to the latest Kernel release, 5.19)

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is probably right, "cache part is not yet implemented in linux kernel". As of now, Mar/2023, the implementation of CXL in Linux kernel is still very limited, due to the fact that there is very limited amount of CXL device/host, and those limited devices/hosts mainly deal with CXL.mem and CXL.io protocols. CXL.cache will be more available in 2024.